# How to resolve workspace error in Power BI?

Tags: service, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to add a member to a workspace, but I am getting the `Couldn't update group` error and the detail behind this is below. I am also not able to change any access levels for any member for any workspace.

> Activity IDe9ffb86b-e0a3-47b2-b2c2-9f84500948b0
> Request ID8609b187-9119-82ff-c1c7-57aecdeb5296
> Correlation ID5b1d2193-331e-ed4b-936d-8a2fab232a43
> Status code500
> TimeWed Nov 25 2020 15:25:42 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
> Service version13.0.14788.65
> Client version2011.3.03863-train
> Cluster URIhttps://wabi-north-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/

Comment: What role are you assigned to in the workspace? If you are a viewer or contributor you might not be able to

Comment: Hi Jon, I am an admin for all workspaces and I have a pro license. I have not encountered this before

Answer (score 0):

I think that MS had a problem with powerbi.com yesterday.
it also happened to me. It works fine now.

btw. the error you posted is only relevant for the MS-techsupport :-). there is not much the community can do with it. except maybe the status code 500

Comment: Yes after an hour i was able to add members to the workspace.